# HttpURLConnection Fixed Length Mode Causes Time Out

Tags: java, android

I'm using an HttpURLConnection to send a POST to a website to log a user in.  My code:

```
byte[] queryBytes = query.toString().getBytes();

/* Open the connection to the login page */
URL url = new URL( urlString );
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

connection.setConnectTimeout( CONNECTION_TIMEOUT );
connection.setReadTimeout( CONNECTION_TIMEOUT );
connection.setRequestProperty( "Accept", "text/html, application/octet-stream" );
connection.setRequestProperty( "Cache-Control", "max-age=0" );

connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode( queryBytes.length );
connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
connection.setRequestProperty( "Origin", ORIGIN );
connection.setRequestProperty( "Referer", REFERER );

/* Add POST data string */
connection.setDoOutput( true );
outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write( queryBytes );
outputStream.close();

/* Execute the POST connection */
int code = connection.getResponseCode();
```

This causes an IOException on the last line with the following logcat:

```
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856): Login: IOException: Read timed out
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:675)
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856):  at libcore.io.Streams.readSingleByte(Streams.java:41)
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:659)
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856):  at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201)
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:560)
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:813)
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856):  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:134)
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856):  at com.myapp.interfaces.SkyWestInterface.login(SkyWestInterface.java:606)
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856):  at com.myapp.services.MonthUpdateService.processIntent(MonthUpdateService.java:181)
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856):  at com.myapp.services.UpdateService.onHandleIntent(UpdateService.java:237)
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856):  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-15 12:03:53.285: E/MyApp(1856):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

If I remove the `connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode( queryBytes.length );` line, then it works.  Why is this line causing the time out?  Is it due to the SSL?

Comment: I think not: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3 Regardless, the presence or absence of that line doesn't affect the problem I'm having.

Comment: try without `connection.setDoOutput( true );`

Comment: Have to have `connection.setDoOutput( true );` to send a POST at all.  When I removed that line it exploded saying GET doesn't support a request body.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried flushing the `OutputStream` after the call to `write()`? The `close()` should call `flush()` automatically, but a call to `flush()` might help.

What's likely happening is that calling `setFixedLengthStreamingMode()` causes the HTTP request to use a `Content-Length: <number>` header instead of a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header. In this mode, the HTTP server on the other end of the wire will not even begin processing the request until it reads `<number>` bytes from the wire. If you don't flush the `OutputStream` and all of the bytes don't end up getting written before the blocking call to `read()` underlying `connection.getResponseCode()` gets made, then the server will never respond, and you'll time out every time.

My hypothesis is that when `Content-Length` is set, then not all of the bytes get written and the server on the other side never starts processing the request, but when `Transfer-Encoding` is set, then either (a) all of the bytes end up getting written for whatever reason, or (b) the server on the other side starts processing the request as soon as the request comes in, and the server pulls in all the bytes over the course of building the response.

At any rate, I'd recommend simply trying out `flush()` after your `write()`. If that works, you could confirm this theory using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). If that doesn't work, I'd recommend breaking out [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to diagnose the problem anyway. :)

Comment: I just tried this, added `outputStream.flush()` right after `write`, but it didn't help.  Shouldn't `outputStream.close()` flush it anyway though?  I'll try Wireshark, but it's an SSL connection so I don't know if I'll be able to see anything.

Comment: Hm. OK. For the SSL connection, you might try setting up a local proxy (like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/home)) so you can see the data going over and coming back using Wireshark. It would be particularly useful to see what the HTTP request headers look like with and without the call to `setFixedLengthStreamingMode`.

Comment: Well I found a solution... doing `connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );` makes it work.  I have no idea why though.  Why would redirecting with a fixed content length cause it to stall out while redirecting with chunked data not?

Comment: @Ralgha Curious. Here's an excerpt from [the documentation for `setFixedLengthStreamingMode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFixedLengthStreamingMode%28long%29): "When output streaming is enabled, authentication and redirection cannot be handled automatically. A HttpRetryException will be thrown when reading the response if authentication or redirection are required. This exception can be queried for the details of the error." Sounds related, although from that reading I would have expected a `HttpRetryException`, not a read timeout. :/